# Linear algebra - eigenvalues, eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n \times n  $ matrix A has pairwise distinct eigenvalues 
$\alpha_{1}, .. \alpha_{n}$ and eigenvectors $a_{1}, ..., a_{n}$,
also matrix B $m\times m$ has pairwise distinct eigenvalues 
$\beta_{1}, .. \beta_{m}$ and eigenvectors $b_{1}, ..., b_{m}$.
Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors for operators:
$$S: Mat_{n\times m} \to Mat_{n\times m}, S(X) = AX + XB^T; $$
$$P: Mat_{n\times m} \to Mat_{n\times m}, P(X) = AXB^T;$$
please help, I would be very grateful if you could explain to me the approach to such problems and suggest the literature for such problems

Comment: Why are you interested in this problem and what have you tried?

Comment: You will find an approach in the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118853/eigenvalues-eigenvectors/3118874#3118874

Comment: James, I supposed that $X = a_{i} \times b_{i}, where $ $a_{i} \in R^n and$ $  b_{i} \in R^m$, then $S(a_{i}\times b_{I}^T) = A(a_{i}\times b_{i}^T) + (a_{i}\times b_{i}^T)B^T= \alpha_{i}a_{i}b_{I}^T+\beta_{i}a_{i}b_{i}^T =  ( \alpha_{I}+ \beta_{i})a_{i}b_{I}^T$

Comment: I am interested in this problem, because I want to understand the main idea of eigenvectors and eigenvalues.